# Rails 2.3.8 testing: How to have my method for *every* assertion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I have a helper module shared by all of my Rails 2.3.8 app's tests.  It provides `setup` and `teardown` methods, among other things.  From looking at the code, it appears as though I *should* be able to define a method named `add_assertion` that will be called by `_wrap_assertion` (Look for `def _wrap_assertion` in [Test::Unit::Assertions 2.1.2](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/svn/tags/2.1.2/lib/test/unit/assertions.rb).)  Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be happening.

Setting a breakpoint in the `setup` method in my helper module, I can verify that `Test::Unit::Assertions` is in its ancestry:

```
(rdb:1) self.class                    
RoutingTest                           
(rdb:1) self.class.ancestors          
[RoutingTest, CandlepinRequestHelper, ActionController::IntegrationTest, \
ActionController::Integration::Runner, ActiveSupport::TestCase, \
ActiveSupport::Testing::Deprecation, ActiveSupport::Testing::Assertions, \
ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown::ForClassicTestUnit, \
ActiveSupport::Callbacks, ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown, \
ActiveSupport::Testing::Default, Test::Unit::TestCase, \
Mocha::Integration::TestUnit::RubyVersion186AndAbove, Mocha::API, \
Mocha::ParameterMatchers, Test::Unit::Util::BacktraceFilter, \
Test::Unit::Assertions, Object, Mocha::ObjectMethods, Socket::Constants, \
InstanceExecHelper, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, \
ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable, InstanceExecMethods, \
Base64::Deprecated, Base64, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel]
(rdb:1) self.class.ancestors.include?(Test::Unit::Assertions)
true
```

but my `def add_assertion` method is being ignored.

So what **is** the recommended way to insert a 'call my method for every assertion' point in the Rails 2.3.8 testing sequence?

Thanks!

Comment: Which ruby version are you using? I've checked and 1.8.7 has _wrap_assertion in its bundled Test::Unit but 1.9.2 does not.

Comment: In the rails 2.x branch the typical way of inserting yourself in to a call stack is with `alias_method_chain`. That allows you to redefine any existing method and keep the old one around so you can call it in your new one. That's out of fashion in rails 3.x though, I believe.

Comment: Another half-baked idea.. It might be instructive to see how rails' fixtures mechanism hooks in. ISTM that it does so at the same point you need to.

Comment: Ruby 1.8.6, Rails 2.3.8.  I'm not seeing how to use `alias_method_chain` here, since `_wrap_assertion` and `add_assertion` are in another module and labelled private.  I don't know how to apply it to such a 'foreign' method..  I will look into the fixture stuff, but I'm anticipating a severe ache in my cephalic nodule as a result. :-)

Comment: Haven't gotten to looking at the fixture stuff, but still on my list..

Comment: We're moving to Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.11, so I'll re-investigate the `_wrap_assertion` approach under those conditions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there's already a suitable hook mechanism for you but I'm sorry to say I don't know it. Could you perhaps create a base class for your test cases, define `setup` there and then remember to call `super` should you need to override it in your tests?

#### EDIT 1

Sorry, I missed the point about needing to hook in to assertions specifically. I realise this doesn't closely match your environment but using rails 3 and ruby 1.9, I've gotten the following to run:

#### test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all

  def assert_with_beards(*args)
    puts "Size 8"
    assert_without_beards(*args)
  end 

  alias_method_chain :assert, :beards

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Running a basic `assert true` style test produces:

```
(in /Users/noodl/temp)
Loaded suite /Users/noodl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails30/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
Size 8
.
Finished in 0.050746 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Usefully, all the assertions I've seen in rails and in the various ruby libraries all ultimately call `assert` in one way or other.

Comment: `setup` and `teardown` are inherited properly from my helper class.  It's the assertion path I'm trying to intercept.